# How much would a regular sized oil rig type platform cost to build?

Tags: drilling

How much would it cost to build an oil rig type platform, that floats like an oil rig, but doesn't have the functions of drilling oil and things like that? Basically what I'm trying to say is, how much would it cost to build a large, floating metal platform to put in the ocean?

Comment: I don't have a figure, but some newspaper articles have given ball park amounts - try there...

Comment: Did you try Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google found an answer in about 5 minutes for me:
http://www.offshore-mag.com/articles/print/volume-72/issue-7/rig-report/reviewing-rig-construction-cost-factors.html

- Drilling equipment - 10% to 30% of total cost.
- Non-drilling-related equipment - similar.
- Total equipment cost - 30% to 60% of total.
- Cost of cheapest jackup rigs - approx. \$200m
- Total cost cheapest semi-submersible or drillship rig - approx. \$500m - \$600m

So you are looking at something like \$100m minimum for a bare platform with no equipment.

Comment: Very good reply, except he seems to be interested in a floater , not a jack-up. So, I think the answer is $ 300 m minimum for the bare floater. Still there are so many variables any answer is like throwing a dart at a bunch of numbers.

Comment: Jackups float, until you lower the legs ;) And a "jackup with no equipment" may not even *have* legs.